# Trigger: Update Contact lookup field from other lookup field on Contact object

Tags: apex, trigger, contact

Hi I am an admin not a developer but my boss asked this request and I am reaching out for help.

On the contact object I have a field named `S_Rapport__c` and it is a user lookup field. There is also a field `S_Rapport_inactive__c` that is a formula field, if the user is active then it populates Active. Then I have a field named `S_Caller__c` that is a user lookup.

I need the trigger to:
If `S_Caller__c` is blank then populate the field with the value in `S_Rapport__c` as long as `S_Rapport_inactive__c` equals Active.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you made any attempts yet? There is a ton of info out there that should help you get started. Try googling trigger to update a user lookup field and if you get stuck, come back and post your code and where you are getting stuck. This link is to a similar question her on the stack exchange: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23298/update-default-value-in-a-lookup-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SFSE. If you are new to SalesForce development then the [SalesForce Workbooks](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_workbook) are a great place to start learning how to develop in Apex.

The code below should do what you are looking for but have a look at the workbooks as well.

```
trigger ContactBeforeTrigger on Contact (before insert, before update) {
    for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        if (c.S_Caller__c == null && c.S_Rapport_inactive__c == 'Active') {
            c.S_Caller__c = c.S_Rapport__c;
        }
    }
```